Schengen 180 day calculator works in Excel, not in Apple Numbers
I have an excel spreadsheet I created on Windows for a friend to caculate how many days someone has spent in the EU's Schengen area over any 180 day period (I've shown an image from it below). It works perfectly in (Windows) excel but doesn't work in Apple numbers.

For any day spent in the Schengen area, you enter a 1 in the In Schengen column for that Date and leave it blank otherwise. The key calculations for each row, the current row, are:

For that row's Date, the start date of the 180 days before it is calculated trivially using: =RC[-3]-180. RC[-3] is the value in the Date column (I prefer to use the RC reference style in Excel, I hope it's clear for those who are unfamiliar with it - btw, this is not the issue as Apple numbers converts these references correctly). This works correctly in numbers.
The number of 1s in the In Schengen column for all the Dates from the 180 day start to the current row are summed in the Days in 180 day period using the formula =SUMIF(R2C1:RC1,">"&RC[-1],R2C3:RC3). This looks at every row, other than the heading row, down to the current row (so not into the future), checks if its Date is after the 180 day start and sums all of the In Schengen entries that meet that crteria. You can see in the image how this goes up 2,3,4,5 etc as and when there's a 1 in the In Schengen column. But in Apple numbers this is always 0 - the SUMIF isn't working.

As I said, this works perfectly in excel but not in Apple numbers. Any ideas what's wrong?

We would have to start guessing wildly as you don’t report what the numbers looks like. Does it throw an error when opening the file? Are specific calculated fields broken? Are you using a formula that is excel specific? My only suggestion would be to try both spreadsheets using the web versions and see if you can make progress…

I've hopefully made it clearer (I found it hard to be clear so thanks for commenting). As far as I can tell, I'm using nothing excel specific. SUMIF in both excel and numbers works the same I think!

About "algorithm": is assumption of "any 180 day period" correct? I read from EU website: "When someone enters the Schengen Area, the 180-day period starts. This means that someone can enter the Schengen Area as many times as they want, but only stay for a total of 90 days, every 180 days.". So it seems to me that this shouldn't be rolling window of days, there should be the same date for 180 day period in column "180 day start".

The rule is that, in ANY 180 day period, a non-EU citizen can only spend up to 90 days in the Schengen area. So the way this is calculated is, for any day, look back 180 days and count up how many days you've spent in Schengen. It is very much a rolling window in which you can enter/leave freely.

Why don‘t you just sum up the past 180 „in Schengen“ days with a relative reference in SUM(), and skip the SUMIF?

Doh! That is so obvious, thanks. I developed my version to avoid errors when there are less than 180 days before in the spreadsheet but I can get around that either by having 180 extra "empty rows" or IFERROR.
